# Custom Tooltip containing list of items in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Trying to show a tooltip containing list of items. How can I achieve it in UWP?
Thanks,
Ela

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to show a tooltip containing list of items.

The ToolTip content property is object type that means  you could inert itemscontrol in it to render list of items,

**for example**

```
<TextBlock Text="Tip">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <ItemsControl>
                <x:String>Hello</x:String>
                <x:String>World</x:String>           
            </ItemsControl>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```